# 2 Divs next to each other with little spacing in between

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create 2 divs that are next to each other but have a little space in between them. This is the following code that i have and the spacing is to far apart. I can't figure out how to set the spacing:

```
            <style type="text/css">
    .formLayout
    {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        border: solid 1px #a1a1a1;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }

    .formLayout label, .formLayout input
    {
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .formLayout label
    {
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    br
    {
        clear: left;
    }
    .box_header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1em;

}
    </style>



        <div class="formLayout" style="float:left;">
        <div class="box_header">
            Account Manager Information
        </div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input id="address1"><br>
        <label></label>
        <input id="address2"><br>
        <label>City</label>
        <input id="address2"><br>
        <label>State</label>
        <input id="zip"><br>
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input id="zip"><br>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="formLayout"  style="float:right;">
        <div class="box_header">
            Client Information
        </div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input id="address1"><br>
        <label></label>
        <input id="address2"><br>
        <label>City</label>
        <input id="address2"><br>
        <label>State</label>
        <input id="zip"><br>
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input id="zip"><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: You've just floated one element to the left and one to the right, if you want them next to each other float them both to the left and add a little margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your second formLayout, you can do:

`style='float:left; margin-left: 20px'`  instead of floating right: http://jsfiddle.net/33Tma/

Obviously you can change the margin to whatever you need.

Also, you should try to avoid inline styling as much as possible.